# How can I fully train my calves?

Tags: calf

I currently train them by just from a standing position going up onto the tips of my toes. Some variations I did were holding weights at the same time or doing one leg at a time which improves balance too.

However it's come to my attention that there are two main groups in the calves and that tip toe exercise I've been doing only works one of them. I've read that for the other one your leg needs to be bent like in a sitting position.

All the sites I saw showed exercises on this machine where you would sit and lift up a weight on your knees.

What can I do at home to workout the other part of my calves. I've tried placing dumbbells on my knees but not only is this uncomfortable but I don't feel tired from this. I don't think I'm getting much benefit from it.

What exercises can I do to train this other muscle group?